# HTML list generated with MYSQL query with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, list

Structure of my table;

```
VARCHAR username,
VARCHAR user_support_message,
VARCHAR user_support_topic,
VARCHAR admin_support_reply,
VARCHAR request_date,
VARCHAR request_time,
BOOL replied,
```

I have a table where I keep user's support requests. What I want to do is to get the unanswered support messages from my database (WHERE REPLIED=NO) and represent them in a html page. I'll try to navigate to each entry, one-by-one and edit them, and save them.

I have no problem while getting the records list with a php script. But I don't know how to represent them properly in a HTML page.

Maybe there is a tool like representing data's gathered from databases.

Comment: My advice is: just take the time to learn both. It's best in the long run. At any rate, if you're running PHP on a web server, it already returns its output in the HTML sent to the client.

Comment: ask Mr. Google for that... he is smart in this area...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will list the results

```
$result = // mysql query response

echo '<table>';

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo '<tr>';

   foreach($data as $v) {
      echo '<td>'.$v.'</td>';
   }

   echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

but you may want to take a look at phpmyadmin if you just want to edit db-entries

Comment: when I try to view each enrty, I'll try to get additional information like screenshots from users. That's why I need this, when I go to "view" page of the record, ill get some extra information about user (from another table) and show the screenshots that are saved to server.

Comment: @Bartu : That means you need to display images that are stored in server?

Comment: @Bartu : Hope [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/50895-display-image-from-mysql-database/) helps you..

Comment: yes, I also store the image link in my table, when I open my record, I will also show the image according to the link.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to loop , just use --html option of mysql command :

```
mysql --html -uroot -e "USE mydb;select * from mytable"
```